# At what memory address is local variable arg2 stored?

Tags: assembly, memory, x86

I am working on a procedure call problem with this code where initially %ebp = 0x800060, and %esp = 0x800040. I'm trying to find what memory address arg2 is stored at.

C Code:

```
int caller()
{
      int arg1 = 534;
      int arg2 = 1057;
      int sum = swap_add(&arg1, &arg2);
      int diff = arg1 - arg2;
      return sum * diff;
}
```

Assembly Code:

```
caller:
     pushl %ebp
     movl %esp, %ebp
     subl $24, %esp
     movl $534, -4(%ebp)
     movl $1057, -8(%ebp)
     leal -8(%ebp), %eax
     movl %eax, 4(%esp)
     leal -4(%ebp), %eax
     movl %eax, (%esp)
     call swap_add
```

Below are the possible answer choices:

1. 0x80003C
2. 0x800040
3. 0x800038
4. 0x800034
5. 0x800024

I keep following through the code and finding that arg2 is stored at 0x800028, which is not in the above answers. I'll show my math through the comments below:

```
caller:
     pushl %ebp  /* ebp pushed onto stack, esp decrease counter by 4, becomes: 0x80003C */
     movl %esp, %ebp /* copies value to ebp, ebp & esp = 0x80003C */
     subl $24, %esp /* 24 is 0x18, esp= 0x800024 */
     movl $534, -4(%ebp) /* arg1 stored at address 0x800038 */
     movl $1057, -8(%ebp) /* arg2 stored at address 0x800034 */
     leal -8(%ebp), %eax /* store arg2 at eax */
     movl %eax, 4(%esp) /* copy arg2 to esp increased by counter of 4, esp + 0x4 = 0x800024 +
     0x4 = 0x800028, so arg2 is stored at 0x800028 */
     leal -4(%ebp), %eax /*same process but arg 1 is copied to esp*/
     movl %eax, (%esp)
     call swap_add
```

So you can see, I end up with 0x800028. I'm sure my math is wrong somewhere, but I'm still a beginner in Assembly, so I just can't tell where. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your analysis in comments is decent, you just went too far, should have stopped at the movl of 1057.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> movl $1057, -8(%ebp) /* arg2 stored at address 0x800034 */
> ```

The way I see it, after this line you're done, you've found where `arg2` is.

Then after that, the addresses of `arg2` and `arg1` are put on the stack because they're arguments of the call to `swap_add`, but none of that changes where the variable `arg2` is. 0x800028 is where the address of `arg2` is put for the purpose of passing it as an argument to `swap_add`, it's not `arg2` itself. If the question was "where is `&arg2` stored" then that could have been the answer.

Comment: That makes much more sense! Thank you, I knew the leal was allocating the memory address onto the stack, but failed to recognize that as the reference to arg2 that is &arg2.

Comment: "the leal was allocating the memory address onto the stack" — I'm not quite sure what you meant by this, but I want to point out that LEA doesn't allocate anything and it doesn't do anything to the stack. It loads the address of the variable into a register.